# "Reloaded site preferences"?

Tags: filenet-p8, filenet, filenet-workplace

In SystemOut logs of a Filenet WorkplaceXT application, I can see "Reloaded site preferences (a big number)" printed every now and then. What is this "big number" printed next to the text "Reloaded site preferences"??

Anyone knows?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it.. Its milliseconds for the time when the site Preferences are being loaded. What an obvious answer was that!! Stupid me...